# LibGDX 3d better camera manipulation

Tags: 3d, camera, libgdx, rotation

In the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
    float x=p1;
    float y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-p2;
    float diff;
    float diff2;
    if(x>touchX){
        diff=(x-touchX)/2;
        cam.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f),new Vector3(0f,1f,0f),-diff);
    }
    if(x<touchX){
        diff=(touchX-x)/2;
        cam.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f),new Vector3(0f,1f,0f),diff);
    }
    if(y>touchY){
        diff2=(y-touchY)/2;
        cam.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f),new Vector3(1f,0f,0f),-diff2);
    }
    if(y<touchY){
        diff2=(touchY-y)/2;
        cam.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f),new Vector3(1f,0f,0f),diff2);
    }


    touchY=y;
    touchX=x;

    // TODO: Implement this method
    return true;
}
```

`Note:TouchX and TouchY are the original touch down positions`
The camera will rotate around on the specified axis (0 1 0) or (1 0 0). Because of this if I rotate it 90 degrees on the x axis and start rotating on the y axis it will seem to spin through the view of the camera rather than follow your finger on the screen. I know why this happens (due to the axis that that are pre-specified and don't change based on the camera's variables) but I wanted to know how I can optimize this so that the camera will follow the touch drag

Comment: I think libgdx's functions are very badly written in the sense that they are not very flexible; ideally the `lookAt` function should take in an `up` vector so that the user can specify the roll of the camera

Comment: You are mixing touch coordinates and world coordinates without converting them. Start here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems. @meowgoesthedog: that's perfectly possible, you are most likely just using it incorrect, either way your comment is irrelevant and doesn't add anything to this question.